# unit testing dotnetnuke module when using ProcessModuleLoadException

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, dotnetnuke

I'm using WebFormsMvp, NUnit, NSubstitue, and FluentAssertions to do TDD while developing a module in DNN 6.1.

As recommended in many DNN related resources, I want to wrap my presenter code in a try/catch block that calls DNN's ProcessModuleLoadException method to log the error and present the user with a friendly error message.

But if I do that, I can't test for specific errors in my unit tests (e.g., I want to test that a (custom) "ExpectedQueryStringParameterNotPresent" error is thrown if the module is called without certain querystring parameters), because the specific exceptions I'm testing for are swallowed by the try/catch block that wraps the code under test.

Is there a way to utilize DNN's global error handling, and still unit test for specific exceptions?

Comment: show us your code please

Answer (score 0):

This is no different in DNN than any other project you would unit test, the ProcessModuleLoadException is just a void that does some internal logging and displaying of the error that was thrown.

Without a code sample, it sounds like you're writing all your code in the Page_Load method. Extract individual functions to their own methods that don't handle their own exceptions (or throw your custom ones) and unit test those.